# Memory leaks using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io

I've found that sockets are not fully destroyed in socket io server side when manually disconnecting them. I've found [this topic on github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/251) useful. While I'm looking for some variable-links that prevent GC from cleaning sockets, I'm asking a question here.

If anyone here encountered the same problem, this would be much help.

the code that does not work:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.removeAllListeners();
});

///...................

socket.disconnect();
```

Workaround that, however, uses restricted library fields:

```
delete io.sockets[url];
io.j = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

actually, this is working as intended, when you disconnect a socket you simply state you're not expecting to receive any more data from that socket right now, to actually destroy the socket you basically do the `delete socket` action. Use this on the disconnect event, ie:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    delete socket; 
})
```

you can also do this on the io.sockets.sockets Object on an external function:

```
function deleteSocket(socketID){
    delete io.sockets.sockets[socketID];
}
```

Comment: you can only `delete` attributes of objects and not the object itself

Comment: io.sockets.sockets[socketID] is still deleted.